# " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths]) ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [219870, 0, 0]

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.7

I'm trying to train some ML algorithms on some data that I collected, but I received an error for input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples. I'm not really sure what variables needs to be changed or not. I've posted my code below to give you a better understanding of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
"""Train and test bigram classifier"""
import dga_classifier.data as data
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
import sklearn
from sklearn import feature_extraction
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


def build_model(max_features):
    """Builds logistic regression model"""
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=max_features, activation='sigmoid'))

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer='adam')

    return model


def run(max_epoch=50, nfolds=10, batch_size=128):
    """Run train/test on logistic regression model"""
    indata = data.get_data()

    # Extract data and labels
    X = [x[1] for x in indata]
    labels = [x[0] for x in indata]

    # Create feature vectors
    print ("vectorizing data")
    ngram_vectorizer = feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer(analyzer='char', ngram_range=(2, 2))
    count_vec = ngram_vectorizer.fit_transform(X)

    max_features = count_vec.shape[1]

    # Convert labels to 0-1
    y = [0 if x == 'benign' else 1 for x in labels]

    final_data = []

    for fold in range(nfolds):
        print ("fold %u/%u" % (fold+1, nfolds))
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, _, label_test = train_test_split(count_vec, y,
                                                                           labels, test_size=0.2)

        print ('Build model...')
        model = build_model(max_features)

        print ("Train...")
        X_train, X_holdout, y_train, y_holdout = train_test_split(X_train, y_train, test_size=0.05)
        best_iter = -1
        best_auc = 0.0
        out_data = {}

        for ep in range(max_epoch):
            model.fit(X_train.todense(), y_train, batch_size=batch_size, nb_epoch=1)

            t_probs = model.predict_proba(X_holdout.todense())
            t_auc = sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score(y_holdout, t_probs)

            print ('Epoch %d: auc = %f (best=%f)' % (ep, t_auc, best_auc))

            if t_auc > best_auc:
                best_auc = t_auc
                best_iter = ep

                probs = model.predict_proba(X_test.todense())

                out_data = {'y':y_test, 'labels': label_test, 'probs':probs, 'epochs': ep,
                            'confusion_matrix': sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, probs > .5)}

                print (sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(y_test, probs > .5))
            else:
                # No longer improving...break and calc statistics
                if (ep-best_iter) > 5:
                    break

        final_data.append(out_data)

    return final_data
```

I've also included my stacktrace because this may be easier to debug.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 95, in <module>
    create_figs(nfolds=1) # Run with 1 to make it fast
  File "run.py", line 34, in create_figs
    bigram_results, lstm_results = run_experiments(isbigram, islstm, nfolds)
  File "run.py", line 23, in run_experiments
    bigram_results = bigram.run(nfolds=nfolds)
  File "/content/dga_predict/dga_classifier/bigram.py", line 44, in run
    labels, test_size=0.2)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/model_selection/_split.py", line 2118, in train_test_split
    arrays = indexable(*arrays)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 248, in indexable
    check_consistent_length(*result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 212, in check_consistent_length
    " samples: %r" % [int(l) for l in lengths])
ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [219870, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file has to be opened in binary mode.

> open(DATA_FILE, 'rb')

Comment: I tried doing this, but I get a response like this in my stacktrace:         
return pickle.load(open(DATA_FILE, "rb"))
EOFError: Ran out of input

Comment: I also tried DATA_FILE.close(), and it still didn't fix my issue.

Comment: @Swooz Did you check if the file is empty?

Comment: Yes, it is empty. I'm not sure why it isn't working.

Comment: "open(DATA_FILE, 'wb').decode("utf-8")" this is not a valid call, because TextIOWrapper object returned by the open() function does not have a method named 'decode'. If you are not getting an error on that line, it would mean the control never entered the if block

Comment: So I made the changes in another Jupyter notebook and it seemed to work and I could see data within traindata.pkl.